# How to determine when the pc turns on windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, event-viewer

I want to know when my PC turns on or off. Is there a way to know this?

I have admin rights.

Comment: Something like this?
https://www.maketecheasier.com/see-pc-startup-and-shutdown-history-in-windows/

Comment: For the current session you can get this from TaskManager->Detailed information tab->right click list header->choose column->check CPU time, then see the time elapsed of System Idle Process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the link in the comment by @SQLTemp, the answer is to examine the System log in the Event Viewer for Event IDs 6005 (Event Log Service startup, proxy for system startup) and 6006 (Event Log Service shutdown, proxy for system shutdown).

There are other useful Event IDs related to system startup and shutdown; Event ID 6013 gives the computer's uptime, 6008 flags a startup after an improper shutdown, and 6009 gives the CPU type detected.

Note that the Event Viewer does have provisions for connecting to a remote computer, so you can get this information for another computer without having to actually sit at its keyboard.

You can also query this information in a PowerShell script using the `Get-EventLog` cmdlet.