# Is there a way to get the (usage time) - time the PC was on - in windows 10 - as is shown in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, task-manager

I previously had a Windows 7 Professional OS 32 bits in my PC, but now I have a Windows 10 Pro - 64 bits.

In Windows 7, every time I turn on the PC, I can check in the Task Manager the "time on" the PC has been since, but, in Windows 10 - even when I disconnect the power cable - I still get the time since I have Windows 10 installed - which is more than 2 days.

In Windows 7, this information is available in the Task Manager - tab "Performance" - section - "System" - item - Usage time.

I wonder why in Windows 10, this time keep even without an energy source and if there is a tool or settings available to get the same results I see in the Task Manager in Windows 7, but in Windows 10.

I like to check Task Manager to see how much time I had my PC turned on - I see it's the "Usage time" value shown in the Task Manager in Windows 7.

---

The following [link](https://superuser.com/questions/1518008/how-to-determine-when-the-pc-turns-on-windows-10) shows a way by using the Event Viewer or a PowerShell script; *(I haven't tried yet)*, but my goal is to watch the time the PC was on without checking the Event Viewer - I think this way is cumbersome for someone who doesn't really understand how those logs can be read or if the script must be executed each time the PC is on.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine when the pc turns on windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1518008/how-to-determine-when-the-pc-turns-on-windows-10)

Comment: I should note that I have _no_ clue where you're looking for this information from Task Manager...

Comment: @JeffZeitlin the information is available in the Task Manager - tab "Performance" - section - "System" - item - Usage time. I edited my question with the clarification.

Comment: You can use cmd or powershell to get this info, if using command prompt type: powershell (get-date) - (gcim Win32_OperatingSystem).LastBootUpTime"  without quotes.

Comment: @Moab - That's likely because of "Fast Boot", as SergiuElmi's answer suggests.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I saw that, I always turn that crap off, cause more issues than the benefit is worth.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-gettickcount is what it shows. That is the time windows has been running since the last boot.

Answer (score 2):

The uptime is not resetting when you turn of your computer because Windows 10 has the feature "Fast Boot" turned on by default.

This feature is caching some system files on each shutdown to allow the computer to boot faster and it would seem the timer is cached as well.

I don't know if there are any workarounds out there, but you can turn off this feature. Note that your computer will actually boot a lot slower (at least in my case, it's really noticeable).

To turn this feature off you can go to Control Panel - Power Options - "Choose What the Power Button do" - "Change settings that are currently unavailable" - Uncheck "Turn off Fast Startup".

Comment: Should be a comment, it does not answer the question being asked.

Comment: I'm not allowed to post it as a comment yet. If anybody can make it a comment I have nothing against it. And It kinda does answer the question, if OP wants to disable this feature!

Comment: Ill leave it for now, it wont get you reps if you can't post it as a comment. Come back when you can comment, don't delete it as this hits your rep.

Comment: Actually yours is the best answer since it solves the problem, just not the question.

Comment: I would like to add "non-pernament" solution here, making full shutdown using shift+shutdown button and add [link explaining this and more](https://www.howtogeek.com/349114/shutting-down-doesnt-fully-shut-down-windows-10-but-restarting-it-does/)

Answer (score 0):

Alternate method is to use the command prompt, type:

> powershell (get-date) - (gcim Win32_OperatingSystem).LastBootUpTime

or

> net stats workstation

you would use this if it Is a Server

> net stats srv

This will give you the time it was powered up so you will have to do the math on how long  its been up.

.

If you prefer using Powershell it would be:

> (get-date) - (gcim Win32_OperatingSystem).LastBootUpTime

I don't know of any faster way.